# show loading when fetching data react

Tags: reactjs, post, upload, fetch

I have a fetch call where users can upload an image and then post it.
However, I want to show the user when the image is being posted, with a loader. My issue is that my loader is always shown. The text `something is loading` is always shown. I just want to show the text while the request is pending. can I please get some help with that=

```
  export default function ImageUpload() {
        const [spinner, setSpinner] = useState(false);
    
      function upload(){
        //some data to post the image
        fetch('my/API/Endpoint'), {
          method: 'post',
          body: body,
        })
       .then(function(data){
          setSpinner(true);
         };
        }
   return (
    <>
       <input type="file"/>
    
        <input onClick={upload}/>
        {spinner && (
        <p>something is loading</p>
        )}
    </>
   );   
        
 }
```

I do want to point out that the logic behind posting and fetching the image does work, I do get status 200! Its only the loading message that does not work

Comment: You should use setSpinner(true) before fetch, inside the fetch, setSpinner(false)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method you have used will always set the spinner to true..bcuz `.then` is always executed after the fetch promise resolves...

You need to set the spinner to true just before the fetch is called and make the spinner false in `.then`.... you need something like this

```
const [spinner, setSpinner] = useState(false);    

function upload(){
 setSpinner(true);

 //some async process
 fetch('my/API/Endpoint'), {
 method: 'post',.0
 body: body,
 }).then(function(data){
 setSpinner(false);
 };
}
```

Comment: Another thing you could also do is use a Page Loader from React-Page-Loading. this has nice loading effects and fully covers the initial screen:

Comment: Wouldn't this make the spinner keep spinning forever if the REST-call fails? Maybe using `setSpinner(prevState => !prevState )` in `.finally` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally

Answer (score 3):

You've inversed no ?

- 1: set spiiner to true
- 2: Set spinner to false after api

  ```
  const [spinner, setSpinner] = useState(false);    

  function upload(){
   setSpinner(true);

   //some data to post the image
   fetch('my/API/Endpoint'), {
   method: 'post',
   body: body,
   }).then(function(data){
   setSpinner(false);
   };
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the spinner state to true AFTER you're fetch is complete. It is then never set to false again. The behavior I'm expecting is that the text is not visible at first, then once the fetch is completed it is always visible.

You are going to want to set the spinner state to true in the upload function and then to false in promise resolver (the .then)

```
function upload(){
        //some data to post the image
        setSpinner(true)
        fetch('my/API/Endpoint'), {
          method: 'post',
          body: body,
        })
       .then(function(data){
          setSpinner(false);
         };
        }
```